# Is there an easy way of finding normalizers and centralizers?

Tags: group-theory

Is there an easy (or fast) way of calculating normalizers or centralizers of a subset? The only way I can think of doing it is by direct calculation, which is very slow.

For example if 
$$S = \{ (1), (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\} \subseteq A_4$$
then to find the elements of the normalizer I have to

- Write down (or calculate) the 12 elements of $A_4$.
- Conjugate each element of $S$ with all 12 elements of $A_4$ and see if the result is in $S$.

So overall I end up doing just short of 48 calculations to find the normalizer of this fairly small subset.

Comment: Lagrange's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=A_4$ then $N_G(S)$ is group containing $S$. Since $|G:S|=3$ then $N_G(S)=S$ or $N_G(S)=G$.

So, take only one elemet $g$ from outside of $S$ and shows that $gSg^{-1}=S$. That means that the second case is valid i.e $S$ is normal in $G$.